# Hide specific ybar when no used (no values) in pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

I am trying to plot the results of a survey. However, I want to turn one bar (the no answer) on and off according to the results. That is, if there is no empty answers, there is no need to show it.

However, how can I hide one of the bars from the plot (given a condition). Also, I am using the `statistics` library to compute the histograms automatically. Is there a way to dynamically change the bins? or is it easier with the `pgfplots` back end?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{data.csv}
a;b;c
4;3;3
1;3;1
1;4;4
1;3;4
2;4;4
2;4;4
4;3;-1
4;4;4
3;3;3
2;4;3
3;3;3
3;2;2
4;4;3
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep = semicolon]{data.csv}\mydata

\makeatletter
\newcommand*\NNC{\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfkeysvalueof{/data point/y}}}
\newcommand*\enlargexlimits{.1} % default value for enlarge x limits 
\pgfplotsset{
  width=\linewidth,
  height=0.5\linewidth,
  grid style={dashed}, % make the grid dashe
  % Bottom nodes 
  calculate full offset/.code={
      \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=true,/pgf/fpu/output format=fixed}
      \pgfmathsetmacro\testmacro{((\pgfplotspointmeta-\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin})*10^\pgfplots@data@scale@trafo@EXPONENT@y)*\pgfplots@y@veclength}
      \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=false}
  },%
  nodes near coords bottom/.style={
    every node near coord/.append style={
      white,
      /pgfplots/calculate full offset,
      yshift=-\testmacro,
      xshift={
        (\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/width}-45pt) % every plot is 45pt smaller then the width
        /(1+2*\enlargexlimits) % correction for enlarge x limits
        /\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/hist/bins} % number of bins
        /2% shift only half of bin width
      }
    },
    nodes near coords={% 
      \pgfmathparse{
        \pgfkeysvalueof{/data point/x}<0.9*\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/hist/data max}?%
          "\noexpand\NNC"%  if true print nodes near coords
          :% if false suppress the additional node near coords
      }\pgfmathresult%
    },
  },%
  % Minimal bar grid, sets the grid on top and white
  minimal bar grid/.style={
    axis on top,
    ymajorgrids, tick align=inside,
    major grid style={draw=white},
    tickwidth=0pt,
    grid style={solid},
    axis x line*=bottom,
    y axis line style={opacity=0},
    legend style={
      font=\footnotesize,
      draw=none %eliminate the border
    },
  },
  minimal ybar interval/.style={
    ybar interval,
    bar interval width=.8pt,
    minimal bar grid,
    nodes near coords={\pgfmathprintnumber[fixed zerofill,precision=0]{\pgfplotspointmeta}},
    nodes near coords bottom,
  },
  bar color/.style={
    gray,
    fill=gray,
  }
}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\myplot}[1]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    minimal ybar interval,
    ymin=0,
    enlarge x limits=0,
    xticklabels={No Ans.,A,B,C,D},
    x tick label style={font=\footnotesize}
  ]
  \addplot +[
    bar color,
    hist={bins=5,data min=0,data max=5}
  ] table [y=#1] {\mydata};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\myplot{a}

\myplot{b}

\myplot{c}

\end{document}
```

For example, for the first two plots, I will like to have only bars from A to D, but in the last one (that has some not answered questions), I will like to show the amount of no answers.

[image]

Comment: I think it would be better if you let pgfplots knows you are using symbolic coordinates. (However `hist/symbolic coords/.style` is wrongly defined in `pgfplotsplothandlers.code.tex`)

Comment: You can't do it within pgfplots `\addplot` command because then everything is already set. What you can do is to start your new command by scanning your columns for the unique values and setting xticklabels based on that.

Comment: @percusse can you provide a way of achieving what you say? I'm not that versed on modifying the tables and change the `xticklabels` on the fly.

Comment: I will try something asap. Sorry for the terse comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Continued from @percuesse's comment:

Add the following lines right after your `\makeatletter`:

```
\makeatletter
\def\pgfplotsplothandlerhistadvancebin#1{
    \pgfplotsarrayselect{#1}\of{pgfp@hist}\to\pgfplots@loc@TMPa%
    \pgfplotsutil@advancestringcounter\pgfplots@loc@TMPa
    \pgfplotsarrayletentry{#1}\of{pgfp@hist}=\pgfplots@loc@TMPa
    % ↑↑↑↑↑↑↑  old  definition  ↑↑↑↑↑↑↑
    % ↓↓↓↓↓↓↓ I added this line ↓↓↓↓↓↓↓
    \message{pglplots express: bin number #1 is now counting to \pgfplots@loc@TMPa.^^J}
}
```

Now you can see how pgfplots counts your data. (See the **Appendix A** below.) It should be relatively easier to

- add something more in `\pgfplotsplothandlerhistadvancebin`, for example `\expandafter\gdef\csname pgfplotstellmeifbin#1isnonempty\endcsname{YES}`.
- pass your data through `\addplot`.
- discard the plot. (but macros defined by `\gdef` remain.)
- start a new plot, this time you know which bar is nonempty.

---

### And then?

Let us start with a new document. Notice that I fix the definition of `hist/symbolic coords/.style` from `pgfplotsplothandlers.code.tex`.

```
\documentclass[border=9,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}
\makeatletter
\def\pgfplotsplothandlerhistadvancebin#1{
    \pgfplotsarrayselect{#1}\of{pgfp@hist}\to\pgfplots@loc@TMPa
    \pgfplotsutil@advancestringcounter\pgfplots@loc@TMPa
    \pgfplotsarrayletentry{#1}\of{pgfp@hist}=\pgfplots@loc@TMPa
    % ↑↑↑↑↑↑↑  old  definition  ↑↑↑↑↑↑↑
    % ↓↓↓↓↓↓↓ I added this line ↓↓↓↓↓↓↓
    \expandafter\gdef\csname bin#1isnonempty\endcsname{YES}
}
\pgfplotsset{
    hist/symbolic coords/.style={
        /pgfplots/symbolic coords={hist/data}{#1},
        /pgfplots/symbolic coords={x}{#1},
    }
}
\pgfplotstableread[row sep=\\]{
    datb\\
    A\\A\\A\\A\\
    B\\B\\
    C\\C\\C\\C\\C\\
    D\\D\\D\\
}\mydatb
\pgfplotstableread[row sep=\\]{
    datb\\
    C\\C\\C\\C\\C\\
    D\\D\\D\\
}\mydatc
\pgfplotstableread[row sep=\\]{
    datc\\
    A\\A\\A\\A\\
    B\\B\\
    D\\D\\D\\
}\mydatd
\pgfplotstableread[row sep=\\]{
    datb\\
    A\\A\\A\\A\\
    B\\B\\
    C\\C\\C\\C\\C\\
}\mydate
\begin{document}
```

---

So we have four plots:

[image]

```
\def\myplot#1{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[ybar interval,ymin=0,xmin=A,xmax=PhantomMax,
                hist={bins=4,symbolic coords={A,B,C,D,PhantomMax}}]
        \addplot table[y index=0]{#1};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
\myplot\mydatb
\myplot\mydatc
\myplot\mydatd
\myplot\mydate
```

---

And then we can report the results:

[image]

```
\def\YES{YES}
\newcount\countofnonzero
\def\myplot#1{
    \countofnonzero=0
    \foreach\i in{0,...,3}{\expandafter\gdef\csname bin\i isnonempty\endcsname{NO}}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[ybar interval,ymin=0,xmin=A,xmax=PhantomMax,
                hist={bins=4,symbolic coords={A,B,C,D,PhantomMax}}]
        \addplot table[y index=0]{#1};
        \end{axis}
        \node at(current bounding box.south)[yshift=-10]{
            \foreach\i in{0,...,3}{
                \expandafter\let\expandafter\YESorNO\csname bin\i isnonempty\endcsname
                \YESorNO
                \ifx\YESorNO
                    \YES\global\advance\countofnonzero1
                \fi
            }
            total=\the\countofnonzero
        };
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
\myplot\mydatb
\myplot\mydatc
\myplot\mydatd
\myplot\mydate
```

---

Finally we can plot them properly:

[image]

```
\def\myplot#1{
    \countofnonzero=0
    \gdef\listognonzero{}
    \foreach\i in{0,...,3}{
        \expandafter\gdef\csname bin\i isnonempty\endcsname{NO}}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[ybar interval,ymin=0,xmin=A,xmax=PhantomMax,
                hist={bins=4,symbolic coords={A,B,C,D,PhantomMax}}]
        \addplot table[y index=0]{#1};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \foreach\i/\a in{0/A,1/B,2/C,3/D}{
        \expandafter\let\expandafter\YESorNO\csname bin\i isnonempty\endcsname
        \ifx\YESorNO\YES
            \global\advance\countofnonzero1
            \xdef\listognonzero{\listognonzero\a,}
        \fi
    }
    \xdef\listognonzero{\listognonzero PhantomMax}
    \edef\numberofnonzero{\the\countofnonzero}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[ybar interval,ymin=0,xmax=PhantomMax,
                hist={bins=\numberofnonzero,symbolic coords/.expanded=\listognonzero}]
        \addplot[fill=red]table[y index=0]{#1};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\myplot\mydatb
\myplot\mydatc
\myplot\mydatd
\myplot\mydate
```

---

### Appendix A

```
pglplots express: bin number 4 is now counting to 1.
pglplots express: bin number 1 is now counting to 1.
pglplots express: bin number 1 is now counting to 2.
pglplots express: bin number 1 is now counting to 3.
pglplots express: bin number 2 is now counting to 1.
pglplots express: bin number 2 is now counting to 2.
pglplots express: bin number 4 is now counting to 2.
pglplots express: bin number 4 is now counting to 3.
pglplots express: bin number 3 is now counting to 1.
pglplots express: bin number 2 is now counting to 3.
pglplots express: bin number 3 is now counting to 2.
pglplots express: bin number 3 is now counting to 3.
pglplots express: bin number 4 is now counting to 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <7> on input line 117.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <5> on input line 117.

Overfull \hbox (10.19409pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 117--118
[][]
 []


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 117--118

 []

pglplots express: bin number 3 is now counting to 1.
pglplots express: bin number 3 is now counting to 2.
pglplots express: bin number 4 is now counting to 1.
pglplots express: bin number 3 is now counting to 3.
pglplots express: bin number 4 is now counting to 2.
pglplots express: bin number 4 is now counting to 3.
pglplots express: bin number 3 is now counting to 4.
pglplots express: bin number 4 is now counting to 4.
pglplots express: bin number 3 is now counting to 5.
pglplots express: bin number 4 is now counting to 5.
pglplots express: bin number 3 is now counting to 6.
pglplots express: bin number 2 is now counting to 1.
pglplots express: bin number 4 is now counting to 6.

Overfull \hbox (10.19409pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 119--120
[][]
 []


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 119--120

 []

pglplots express: bin number 3 is now counting to 1.
pglplots express: bin number 1 is now counting to 1.
pglplots express: bin number 4 is now counting to 1.
pglplots express: bin number 4 is now counting to 2.
pglplots express: bin number 4 is now counting to 3.
pglplots express: bin number 4 is now counting to 4.
pglplots express: bin number 0 is now counting to 1.
pglplots express: bin number 4 is now counting to 5.
pglplots express: bin number 3 is now counting to 2.
pglplots express: bin number 3 is now counting to 3.
pglplots express: bin number 3 is now counting to 4.
pglplots express: bin number 2 is now counting to 1.
pglplots express: bin number 3 is now counting to 5.

Overfull \hbox (10.19409pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 121--122
[][]
 []


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 121--122

 []
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on the "relatively easier" part of actually removing the plot. Still that goes beyond me, and that is the purpose of the question.

Comment: @adn In case I do not end up with a concrete example, here is what I thought: percuesse suggests that you should write a so called **preprocessor**. And my answer is about using `tikzpicture` itself as a preprocessor. Now you have at most 32 cases to handle and it should be ... uh... easy... in some sense.

Comment: I understand your idea, but if I want to display the graph with the removed bins alone, I can't use the solution. As the first tikzpicture needs to process the data. (Or am I doing something wrong?) I want to obtain only the graphs in red, not the blue (purple) ones.

Comment: @adn Try `\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,opacity=0]`.

Comment: Using the `overlay` and `opacity` add a spurious space. Is there a way to cleanly remove the `tikzpicture`?

Answer (score 4):

You can sort your table based on the column you want to show. Then you can count the unique items and match the indices with the respective labels. This is of course pretty convoluted way of doing things and I think can be proposed as a feature request to Christian Feuersänger. However I've noticed that there is some sensitivity in the bin computations regardless. Just write `bins=3` in your own code and the second one will report `0,7,6` as the element count might be the relative magnitude and rounding issue. And that can be a bug report too.

I've removed most of the axis options to reduce the clutter.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable,xstring}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}

\newcount\mybincount
\pgfplotstableread[col sep = semicolon]{
a;b;c
4;3;3
1;3;1
1;4;4
1;3;4
2;4;4
2;4;4
4;3;-1
4;4;4
3;3;3
2;4;3
3;3;3
3;2;2
4;4;3
}\mydata

\newcommand{\myplot}[1]{%
\mybincount=0\def\myuniqueindex{}
\pgfplotstablesort[sort key=#1]\mysorteddata\mydata
\pgfplotstableforeachcolumnelement{#1}\of\mysorteddata\as\cell{%
\ifx\cell\prevvalue%IF they are the same ignore
\else% Otherwise 
\xdef\prevvalue{\cell}% Make this the new previous value
\global\advance\mybincount by1% add to the unique items count and index
\expandafter\xdef\expandafter\myuniqueindex{\myuniqueindex,\cell}%
\fi%
\foreach\x/\y in{-1/{No Ans.},1/A,2/B,3/C,4/D}{% Replace strings with indices
\IfSubStr{\myuniqueindex}{\x}{%
\StrSubstitute{\myuniqueindex}{\x}{\y}[\myuniqueindex]%Then remove the preceeding comma
\IfBeginWith{\myuniqueindex}{,}{\StrGobbleLeft\myuniqueindex{1}[\myuniqueindex]}{}%
\global\let\myuniqueindex\myuniqueindex%
}{}}%
}\show\myuniqueindex\showthe\mybincount%
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[width=.4\textwidth,
    ybar interval,
    bar interval width=.8pt,
    ymin=0,ytick={1,...,6},
    enlarge x limits=0,
    xticklabels/.expand once=\myuniqueindex,
    x tick label style={scale=0.5}
  ]
  \addplot +[fill=gray,hist={bins=\the\mybincount,data min=0,data max=5}] table [y=#1] {\mydata};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}}
\begin{document}

\myplot{a}\myplot{b}\myplot{c}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: There is a problem with your code. When one value comes not in order the values are lost. For example, the second graph has no `B` count, and it should be one. And I think it is due to the order of the parsing, because you assume that they will come in order.

Comment: @adn See the comment above. It's not due to my answer. It makes a wrong rounding I think. Try it also in your code as I mentioned in my answer. The value order is not important as I sort them before processing so that cannot explain the behavior